# Several processes accessing singleton object at the same time

Tags: c++, singleton, singleton-type

It was a basic question on singleton class, I knew that we can have only one object for a singleton class across the lifetime of  the application..

what happens when several processes accesses the same object at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "processes"? Do you mean *threads*? And *how* do the threads "access" the singleton *object*? Are the functions called reentrant, or do they modify shared data?

Comment: It entirely depends on the nature of your singleton. You probably need to put in place some synchronization mecanism depending on the nature of the singleton. And please ask only one question at a time. Anyway the second question is far too broad.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sry, i have edited the question accordingly....

Comment: @MichaelWalz So we need to provide locking mechanism explicitly for several processes to access it simultaneously

Comment: Like both me and Michael said, it *depends*. What is your programming and the singleton object *doing*? And please learn the difference between *process* and *thread*, I still think you mean the latter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  no I'm speaking about process..not threads

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am planning to implement a socket library which opens a client socket. I have several processes which links this library and uses this socket for sending data to server socket..i am implementing that in c++

Comment: Then how are you using a singleton object from multiple processes? Are you using an uncommon operating system without protection between processes? Is the singleton using shared memory of some kind? Please elaborate.

Comment: Unless you have a dynamic library with its own memory space, don't do whatever you're planning on doing. Don't share data between processes unless the goal is to actually share memory and data between the processes (and then you would not need a networking library for that). And for sockets and networking, using singletons is probably going to turn out to be the anti-pattern it is famed for.

Comment: This question is either too broad (how to access a shared resource from multiple processes) or unclear (the question is being clarified/changed in the comments) voting to close.